# PyQt Unconstrained Mouse Vector

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have created a widget that needs very subtle mouse control, but when the mouse reaches the edge of the screen i have to recenter the mouse to get movement input.

Is there a way using PyQt to get the mouse vector or an other form of unconstrained mouse axis?

Comment: Could you provide some code to work with? I don't entirely understand what you mean by "unconstrained mouse axis." Are you attempting to receive `mouseEvent`s outside of a given window?

Comment: What i mean is that if you pull your cursor to the left, you will reach the edge of the screen and the cursor no longer moves, so any movement to the left is not being accounted for in your mouse.x.y. I see a few apps are pulling the mouse cursor to the center and to get the delta, but i thought that there would maybe be a better solution.